# How do I add a string to another string and remove the overlapping part?

Tags: python, string, merge, overlapping

How do I add one string to another and remove a part in the middle if it's double?

I really don't know how to explain this but this is what I want to do:

Lets say

```
string1 = "abcde"

string2 = "cdefg"
```

How would I create a variable that's string1+string2 but with the "cde" part only once?

I'm looking for something like:

```
string3 = merge(string1, string2)
```

That would make string3 "abcdefg" and not "abcdecdefg"

I couldn't find it with google so that's why i'm asking here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Work it out on paper first.  See what the steps are.  Then write the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if there is an overlap first and then append only the non-overlapping parts:

```
# Find overlap if there is any
for i in range(1, len(string2)):
    if string1.endswith(string2[:i]):
        k = i

# Concatenate strings:
string3 = string1 + (string2 if k is None else string2[k:])
```

Or even simpler, set `k` to zero first:

```
# Find overlap if there is any
k = 0
for i in range(1, len(string2)):
    if string1.endswith(string2[:i]):
        k = i

# Simply concatenate them
string3 = string1 + string2[k:]
```

Comment: With `string1 = "abede"` and `string2 = "edefg"`, you get `'abedeedefg'` instead of 'abedefg'.

Answer (score 1):

We can look for each occurence of the first character of `s2` in `s1`, and test if the rest of `s1` from this occurence is the start of `s2`. We need to do that from the start of `s1` towards the end, in order to be sure to get the largest possible overlap.

```
import re

def fusion(s1, s2):
    for m in re.finditer(s2[0], s1):
        if s2.startswith(s1[m.start():]):
            return s1[:m.start()] + s2
    # no overlap found
    return s1 + s2


string1 = "abede"
string2 = "edefg" # overlap: 'ede'

print(fusion(string1, string2))
# abedefg
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be simply implemented with python set() as folows..

```
>>> string1 = "abcde"
>>> string2 = "cdefg"
>>> string3 = string1 + string2
>>> print (''.join(sorted(set(string3))))
abcdefg
```

> **Explanation:**  `set()` removes the duplicate elements, `sorted()` sorts, and the `join()` combines it all back.

Comment: with string1 = "abedde", string2 = "eddefghi" you get 'abdefghi' instead of 'abeddefghi'